# jquery and php search

Tags: php, jquery, sql

can anybody help me with this? i know my sql is right but all i get is "there are no listings"
EDIT:  if there us anyone here, can you take a look at the updated SQL? its just returning multiples of the data?

Getsearch.php

```
       <?php
include("config.php");

 $partialsearch = $_POST['partialsearch'];

   $mysearch = ""select games.game_id,games.game_name, games.game_description,  
genre.genretype, games.gamepic, developer.dev_name,developer.dev_id,      developer.devpic, sub_genre.sub_g
 from games 
  inner join genre on genre.genre_id=games.genre_id
   inner join developer on developer.dev_id=games.dev_id
     inner join sub_genre on sub_genre.sub_id=games.Sub_g
    like games.game_name = '%".$partialsearch."%'";
  $result = mysqli_query($connection, $mysearch);
  if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0)
  while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
 {
    $name = $row['game_name'];
   echo $name;
 }
else {
echo "there are no listings";
}


 ?>
```

here is the input box

```
 <div id ="search">
 <h1>Looking for Something?</h1>
 <input type"text" onkeyup="getsearch(this.value)"/>
 </div>
```

the script

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 function getsearch(value){
$.post("getsearch.php",{partialsearch:value}, function(data){
$('#results').html(data);   
 });
 }
```

cript source

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: When you have achieved what you wanted, please see http://stackoverflow.com/q/60174/299756 for why your code is vulnerable to sql injections.

Comment: Thank you everyone who helped me on this

Comment: i edited the SQL if anyone is still interested,.

Answer (score 4):

Fix the `query` -

```
$mysearch = "SELECT game_name from games WHERE game_name LIKE '%". $partialsearch. "%'";
```

Add the `bracket`s -

```
if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
        $name = $row['game_name'];
        echo $name;
    }
} else {
    echo "there are no listings";
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Your sql query is not right.

Instead of

```
$mysearch = "SELECT game_name from games WHERE game_name LIKE'%partialsearch%'";
```

use

```
$mysearch = "SELECT game_name from games WHERE game_name LIKE '%".$partialsearch."%'";
```

You were always looking for game what is named like "partialsearch", not what you have in input. You have to set variable value there.

And you are missing bracket.

```
if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0){
  while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
  {
    $name = $row['game_name'];
    echo $name;
  }
} // This bracket was missing
else {
  echo "there are no listings";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

change your query

```
$mysearch = "SELECT game_name from games WHERE game_name LIKE'%".$partialsearch."%'";
```